# CS amplifier feedback stability

Tags: amplifier, feedback, stability, phase-margin, common-source

I playing with JFET Common Source amplifier with feedback loop. I am simulating the design showed here. https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slpa018/slpa018.pdf?ts=1669662908797&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

I followed the steps for feedback stability analysis (breaking the loop, inserting the inductor and cap etc.) I get from simulator the same results as are presented in the paper. What I am not sure about is phase margin evaluation. The phase of the circuit starts at -90 deg and at point when gain is 0 is -266 deg. I thought that the phase margin of this circuit is than just 4 degree (-266 + 90 = -176, 4 degree to -180). They are claiming that the phase margin of the circuit is 87.4 deg (page 8 in attached paper).

Could me someone explain what is right phase margin of the circuit and what is proper calculation?
**Standard schematic**
[image: Standard schematic]
**Stability analysis schematic**
[image: Stability analysis schematic]
**Simulation**
[image: Simulation]

[image]

Comment: Isn't is a common gate circuit?

Comment: I added the standard schematic in which amplifier operates.

Answer (score 1):

Peter, I agree with you. The comments to the phase margin measurements are confusing - more than that: To me, the comments are really wrong.
I think, they have applied not the correct definition for the phase margin.
(Sorry to say - you have made a similar error).

Let me explain: Sometimes there is a confusion in the phase margin definition because - unfortunately - in the literature, there are two different definitions for loop gain:

**1)** Loop gain is the product of all gains within the loop - WITHOUT taking into account the sign inversion(s) at the summing node resp. within the loop.

**2)** Loop gain is the gain which can be measured, calculated or simulated by opening the loop at a suitable point and inject a test signal (as you did, with an inductor because of the DC operating point). In this case, of course all sign inversions within the loop are taken into consideration.

**Phase margin:**

- case 1): The critical phase (at zero magnitude) is -180 deg
- case 2): The critical phase it at -360 deg (identical to zero deg).

Therefore, in the case under discussion the phase margin is **PM=360-267.4=92.6 deg**.

Comment: But what about initial phase ? Shouldn't I somehow take into consideration that the phase already starts at -90 deg ? And one additional question. Which points are suitable for the breaking the loop ?

Comment: Normally, the phase must start at -180deg (neg. feedback). However, due to simulation with Cd (highpass) the phase starts at -180+90=-90 deg. Thats OK - and this has no influence on the applicability of the criterion: Stability limit at unity loop gain (unity magnitude and zero phase). When you are using an inductor and a coupling-C the selection of a suitable point is uncritical. As an alternative, you could use a test voltage source directly at the opamp output BETWEEN the output node and the first node called VF1